# PHP - Loop not behaving as expected

Tags: php

I am working with a for loop in PHP which is not working as intended. The loop outputs a form to the page with its own validation script. However, once run, the loop never ends!

```
for ($noemployments=0; $noemployments < 3; $noemployments++) { 
    if ($noemployments >=9) {
        break 2;
    }

    $noemploymentsErr.$noemployments="";

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST['no_empreturns".$noemployments"'])) {
            $noemploymentsErr.$noemployments = "This is a required field.";
        } else {
            $no_empreturns.$noemployments = test_input($_POST['no_empreturns".$noemployments"']);
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$/", $no_empreturns.$noemployments)) {
                $noemploymentsErr.$noemployments = "Illegal characters have been entered.";
            }
        }
    }

    print "<label for='no_returns'>Employment Name".$noemployments.":</label>
        <input type='text' id='no_returns' class='form-control' name='no_empreturns".$noemployments."' placeholder='Employment name' maxlength='20'>";
    print "<strong>".$noemploymentsErr.$noemployments."</strong>";

 }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: On this line: `$noemploymentsErr.$noemployments="";` You're actually setting `$noemployments=""` and then on the loop interation when ++ is called - it's being casted to a number (0) and +1 added - 1. So you're actually resetting your loop variable at every iteration causing the loop to never stop running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$noemploymentsErr.$noemployments="";
```

Doesn't do what you think.  It sets `$noemployments` to and empty string every time through the loop, which evaluates to `0` and `0 < 3`.  So the loop never ends.

Better would be to use an array:

```
$noemploymentsErr[$noemployments] = "";
```

But if you don't use this later then there is no need to keep the errors individually, just:

```
$noemploymentsErr = "";
```